# How do you remove or hide the 'Permalink' in comments?

Tags: 7, comments, theming

Does anyone know how to remove or hide the 'permalink' in the comments section (i.e on posted comments).Here is a copy of one of my comments -

" Permalink Submitted by Jade K on Fri, 11/11/2011 - 14:28"

Additionally, does anyone know how to rename or remove 'submitted by' from comments?

Answer (score 6):

Copy the default comment comment.tpl.php into your theme directory:

```
cp /your_drupal_path/modules/comment/comment.tpl.php /your_drupal_path/sites/all/themes/mytheme/comment.tpl.php
```

Search and change the following lines into your theme's path comment.tpl.php:

From:

```
<div class="submitted">
<?php print $permalink; ?>
<?php print $submitted; ?>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="submitted">
<!-- Do not show Permalink on comments -- it will still have a link on the comment title
<?php print $permalink; ?> -->
<?php print $submitted; ?>
</div>
```

This will do the magic!

Comment: The simplest and the best.

Answer (score 4):

This really depends on what theme you are using.  Oddly enough, I can't find a theme on my machine that includes the permalink link like that, but you should take a look at the **comment.tpl.php** for the theme you are using.

The default one for Zen for Drupal 6 has this in it:

```
<div class="submitted">
  <?php
    print t('Submitted by !username on !datetime.',
      array('!username' => $author, '!datetime' => $created));
  ?>
</div>
```

If you are using Drupal 7, then there is a decent chance that the text is coming from [template_preprocess_comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7).

I both cases, note where the text is coming from: the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function.

You could just edit the text, but that is not the proper way to handle it.  t() handles translation, but it also can handle custom localization.  These are done with string overrides, which can be handled several different wants. The [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module is the easiest way.  You can also do them in your **settings.php**.  I don't have the link handy for that syntax, though.

If you want to hide either of these in Drupal 7, then you need to implement your own template_preprocess_comment() and [unset()](http://php.net/unset) `$permalink` and/or `$submitted`.  For Drupal 6, just remove that code blip from the template file.

Comment: thanks. i  am using drupal 7 and the zen sub theme, sorry i neglected to mention that.

Comment: i found the following code in my comment.tpl.php -                            <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $permalink; ?>
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div> - but when i try changing the text nothing happens.

Comment: OK, that means that you need to use String Overrides.  Did you install this?  Look at the strings in the  template_preprocess_comment link above, and then set up your replacements.

Comment: you could just remove <?php print $permalink; ?> from comment.tpl.php. The "submitted by" is in node.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

better add this in your css: .permalink {display: none;}

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css
.permalink {font-size:0px;}

Comment: or `display:none`